# Failure in FFMPEG compilation on Ubuntu 16.04 - ‘AOM_ERROR_RESILIENT_PARTITIONS’ undeclared here (not in a function)

Tags: ffmpeg

After I had solved the compile issue with libfdk-aac ([Failure in FFMPEG compilation on Ubuntu 16.04 - recipe for target 'libavcodec/libfdk-aacenc.o' failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1074181/failure-in-ffmpeg-compilation-on-ubuntu-16-04-recipe-for-target-libavcodec-li)), the new problem in compiling FFMPEG was raised:

```
libavcodec/libaomenc.c:744:109: error: ‘AOM_ERROR_RESILIENT_PARTITIONS’ undeclared here (not in a function)
  " is still done over the partition boundary.",       0, AV_OPT_TYPE_CONST, {.i64 = AOM_ERROR_R
                                                                                     ^
ffbuild/common.mak:60: recipe for target 'libavcodec/libaomenc.o' failed
make: *** [libavcodec/libaomenc.o] Error 1
```

As mentioned on the FFMPEG's issue tracking system (http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7433), the error is related to last commit on VP8 library ('Remove vestigial VP8 token partition support.')

Is there anay idea?

Comment: Same answer as the last one - use an older version of libaom.

Comment: Issue fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gyan. It seems that the issue is fixed now (http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=b69ea742ab23ad74b2ae2772764743642212a139).